# MySql Error ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, cmd

I'm following [Vogella's tutorial on MySQL](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQL/article.html) and I'm hitting a brick wall when I try to imitate the example. I've installed MySQL, and as he instructs I run it from the command line. When I do so, I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.0.9>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ******
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.0.9>
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is the mysql-server started?

Comment: Whenever I try (i.e. when I enter `mysql` into the prompt) it gives me the same error

Comment: You are using the mysql client which will now try to connect to a mysql-server running on your machine. The error-message looks like there is no such server running.

Comment: Problem with the firewall perhaps?

Comment: How do I get a server running? The article doesn't mention it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is very simple. The problem is the mysql service is not started. So we first need to start the mysql service before 'mysql -u user_name -p' command.
To do that, navigate to 'bin' folder of mysql in command prompt.
E.g:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>
```

In your case probably,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 6.0.9\bin>
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\bin>
```

or

If you have XAMPP installed, then to start mysql associated with it, navigate to

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>
```

then type the command `mysqld -u root -p`

It will output:

> '2017-04-04 13:40:27 8536 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.21-MariaDB) starting as process 5640 ...'

This shows mysql is started.

Now type your command `mysql -u root -p`, it will work for sure.

Comment: My issue was using WAMPServer.  For some reason it installed with a config of port 3308 instead of 3306, so connecting locally worked, but remotely failed until I used --port 3306 for mysql.exe.  I recommend editing my.ini to change to 3306 and restarting mysqld locally.

Answer (score 1):

try restarting the MYSQL app in the XAMPP control panel. It worked for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Open the Xampp control panel and start the mysql module. For wamp, do the same.
 This is the simplest ever solution I've got !

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, I started MySQL server with the below command as an administrator in one cmd window and then tried connecting mysql in another cmd window, it worked !!

cmd window 1:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld

cmd window 2:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: ************
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.26

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

Answer (score 1):

Before running the command:

```
mysql -u user_name -p
```

There are few steps to take.

---

**Assuming you don't have `XAMPP` installed**

> **Approach 1**

- Navigate to `bin` folder of MySQL.

  ```
   cd 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin'
  ```
- NOTE: Check for the version of `MySQL Server` on your machine. To do this, run:

  ```
  cd 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\'
  ls
  ```
- You'll see the version installed, then navigate to the `bin` folder. It will look like this:

  ```
  cd 'MySQL Server 8.0\bin'
  ```
- Then run the command:

  ```
  mysqld -u root -p
  mysql -u root -p
  ```
- This should take you into MySQL Shell.

> **Approach 2**

- To make it easier to invoke MySQL program anywhere in the terminal, add MySQL bin directory path to the Windows system PATH environment variable. Visit [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html)
- Now, MySQL command can be run from anywhere using `git bash`.

---

**If you have `XAMPP` installed, start MySQL associated with it**

- Navigate to its directory:

  ```
  cd 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin'
  ```
- Then try the command:

  ```
  mysqld -u root -p
  mysql -u root -p
  ```
- This should take you inside MySQL Shell.

> If it does'nt work, start MySQL from the `XAMPP` Control Panel and run:

```
  mysql -u root -p
```

- This should take you into MySQL Shell.

---

It worked! Exit the Shell:

```
\q
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start->Run and type services.msc. That's how you get to windows services window. Look for MySQL Server, Right Click, Start Service.

You could also get to Windows Services Window by Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services

If there's no such service MySQL Server, then install MySQL Server from here
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: Also, to get to the Run prompt, you could press Super (Windows logo key) + R

Answer (score 0):

mysql --protocol=TCP -P3306 -u user -p

Comment: It's good to have additional comments along with your solution.